# Generate "table" with <div>

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like generate the representation below by `<div>`. The constraints :

- the full size = 100%
- the first + second column = 50%, the 3rd + 4th column = 50%
- the first column is smaller than the second, the second take "the rest of the place", same for column 3 and 4 :)
- the 3rd lines, combines 2 cells
- the last line combine 4 cells
- don't worry about the color :)

PS : no debate table vs div ;-)

[image]

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to represent with this structure?

Comment: How about posting your HTML and CSS and telling us where you get stuck?

Comment: It's possible, yes. But you want to 'generate the representation below by `div`'? Where's the `div` coming from? As @Alec says, your html (and css) would be a great help in answering the question.

Comment: If what you're actually going to display in these "table cells" is statistics, lists or other typical tabular data, you should indeed use a `table` and not a bunch of `div`-elements. Of course, using `div` could be perfectly legitimate as well.

Comment: Would divs with `display: table-cell` be considered cheating?

Comment: I posted a Table Answer (but got a -5) because it wasn't what the user wanted (though I'm adding it as a comment to my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my proposed markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col half">
    <div class="col narrow">(1)</div>
    <div class="col remainder">(2)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col remainder">
    <div class="col narrow">(1)</div>
    <div class="col remainder">(2)</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col half">(3)</div>
  <div class="col remainder">(3)</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  (4)
</div>​
```

And styles:

```
/* structure */
.row { clear: both; overflow: hidden; }
.col { float: left; }
.half { width: 50%; }
.narrow { width: 30%; }
.remainder { float: none !important; overflow: hidden; }

/* skin: just for demo */
.row { text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; }
.half { background: #fcc; }
.narrow { background: #ccf; }
.remainder { background: #cfc; }
```

The first two rows are split into half. In each half are two cells: the first is called `narrow` and is floated. I put 30% on the width for this one just for the demo (note: that's 30% of the half of the row). The other column is called `remainder` and is *not* floated. It uses overflow to set its own rendering context, which means it fills the block to the right of the floated column.

You can have more floated columns (left or right), but only one remainder.

I put it up [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8S9jH/2/): play with it.

Comment: I definitely like your CSS styling better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the misread, my previous Answer was using TABLE when you wanted to use DIV.
Also, note that if you want to use Borders, you have to offset the width percentage. (The other answer on this page may not display properly)

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper { width:100%; background-color:#ddd; text-align:center; float:left;}
.quarter-row { width:25%; background-color:#bbb; float:left;  }
.half-row { width:50%; background-color:#999; float:left; }
.full-row { width:100%; background-color:#777; float:left; }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="quarter-row">1</div><div class="quarter-row">2</div><div class="quarter-row">3</div><div class="quarter-row">4</div>
  <div class="half-row">1 (50% width)</div><div class="half-row">2 (50% width)</div>
  <div class="full-row" >1 (100% width)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is how I did it using a TABLE in my first downvoted answer <TABLE BORDER=2 CELLPADDING=4>
<TR><TD>1</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>4</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>1</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>4</TD></TR>
<TR><TH COLSPAN=2>something</TH> <TH COLSPAN=2>something</TH></TR>
<TR><TH COLSPAN=4>something</TH></TR>
</TABLE> (This is simply for reference since I deleted my other answer as it was getting downvoted)

Comment: And using TABLES makes it easier to add borders without having to adjust width percentages or other style attributes like you have to do with DIV's

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    div.row { width: 99.9%; border: 1px solid black; height: 1em;}
    div.cell2 {border: 1px solid black; height: 1em; width: 49.9%; float: left;}
    div.cell4 {border: 1px solid black; height: 1em; width: 24.9%; float: left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "row">
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
    </div>
    <div class = "cell2"></div><div class = "cell2"></div>
    <div class = "cell4"></div><div class = "cell4"></div>  <div class = "cell4"></div><div class = "cell4"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The style is in the header, but it really should be in its own CSS file.

Comment: just a heads up but the borders throw off the alignment of your cells on my browser.

Comment: As a side note: tables are not always bad. They get a bad rep due to people using them inappropriately for layout, but if you are displaying tabular data, you really should be using tables. They're easier for older screen readers to work with (508 compliance huzzah!)

Comment: @KennyCason: Borders can be a problem, cross-browser. If I were to really, really do this, it would be quite a bit longer, with lots of border-lefts and firsts.

Comment: right. I was just pointing it out for the sake of the question asker, that way he would at least know why it may not work for him. :P

Comment: Of course it's just for the demo: borders don't work well with percentages and `width:49.9%` is just praying that it will fill the width without overflowing... in reality I'd put another div inside each column for the borders instead.